# Wget speed result

Tags: python, wget

I have a problem, I need the output of the command in python and exactly get the download speed from the wget command. My code is :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3


import os
import re
import subprocess

command = "wget ftp://ftp:password@172.17.1.129:1111/test.bin -p -nv "
process = subprocess.check_output(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
ftp_result = re.findall(('\d+.\d+'),process)
        
print (ftp_result)
```

TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

On Python 3, `subprocess` returns `bytes` unless you explicitly request decoding.

Also, [you generally want to avoid `shell=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) if you are not actually *using* the shell for anything.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

# import os  # not used
import re
import subprocess

process = subprocess.check_output(
    ["wget", "ftp://ftp:password@172.17.1.129:1111/test.bin", "-p", "-nv"],
    text=True)   # this is the beef
ftp_result = re.findall(('\d+.\d+'),process)
        
print (ftp_result)
```

Notice also how `check_output` already defaults to capturing the output, so you don't need to explicitly direct `stdout` to a `subprocess.PIPE`, either.

Perhaps a more robust solution would be to switch to `curl`, which allows you to separately retrieve just the download speed using a format specifier.